# Implicit Conversion from Double to Single

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim BP As Single, WVP As Single, x As Single
...
x *= (101.325 / BP) * ( BP / (BP - WVP) )
```

The code compiles and seems to run correctly, but is underlined with the message "Implicit Conversion from 'Double' to 'Single'"

Why would this be an implicit conversion if each of the variables is cast as a Single? Is this something I should worry about or change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`101.325` is a `Double` literal.
Therefore, your code is actually multiplying a `Double` by a `Single`, creating a `Double`.

You need to write `101.325F` to force the literal to be a `Single`.

Comment: Thanks. Coming from Python where ints and floats are distinguished by the (.) only.

Answer (score 0):

`101.325` is a double, that is being  cast to a single.